# SPARQL query coming up empty

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I'd like to query [DBPedia](http://dbpedia.org/About) with SPARQL to select car manufacturers (of France to start), but I have no idea how to do this.

I started with this query:

```
select distinct * where {
  ?carManufacturer dbpedia-owl:product <http://dbpedia.org/page/Automobile> .
  ?carManufacturer dbpprop:locationCountry "France"@en
} LIMIT 100
```

However, it returns an empty result set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well it's so uncommon framework/script, and I highly recommend you to contact the framework developers, you might get your answer sooner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re using the wrong URI to identify DBPedia resources.  On DBPedia, `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Automobile` refers to the noun ‘automobile’, while `http://dbpedia.org/page/Automobile` refers to *a page describing the noun ‘automobile’.*  Thus,

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
  ?carManufacturer dbpedia-owl:product <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Automobile>.
  ?carManufacturer dbpprop:locationCountry "France"@en.
} LIMIT 100
```

works just fine.

However, if you want to be a bit more idiomatic, you can use a bit of syntactic sugar to eliminate the subject repetition in your query.  DBPedia also loads `http://dbpedia.org/resource/` as prefix `dbpedia`, so you can actually eliminate all URIs from your query entirely:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
  ?carManufacturer dbpedia-owl:product dbpedia:Automobile;
                   dbpprop:locationCountry "France"@en.
} LIMIT 100
```